# Notepad++ help: Adding attribute after node

Tags: notepad++

```xml
<canvas name="A" width="11" height="11">
</canvas>
<canvas name="B" width="22" height="22">
</canvas>
<canvas name="A" width="33" height="33">
</canvas>
<canvas name="B" width="44" height="44">
</canvas>
```

Apologies if this has been asked before. I want to add a line that says `<additionalattribute>` every after `<canvas name="B" ... </canvas>` node. Is that possible? Given that each `<canvas name="B"` node has different values within the tags.

So the ideal outcome will be:

```xml
<canvas name="A" width="11" height="11">
</canvas>
<canvas name="B" width="22" height="22">
</canvas>
<additionalattribute>
<canvas name="A" width="33" height="33">
</canvas>
<canvas name="B" width="44" height="44">
</canvas>
<additionalattribute>
```

Answer (score 1):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `<canvas name="B"[\s\S]+?</canvas>\K`
- Replace with: `\n<additionalattribute>`
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
<canvas name="B"        # literally
[\s\S]+?                # 1 or more any character including newline, not greedy
</canvas>               # literally
\K                      # forget all we have seen until this position
```

**Replacement:**

```
\n                      # linefeed, you can use \r\n for windows EOL
<additionalattribute>   # the tag to add
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]